# Lorentz transformations in General Relativity confusion

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

Given a Minskowskian metric spacetime $(M,\mathcal{O},\mathcal{A}^{\uparrow},\nabla,g)$ and given two parametrized curves $\gamma:I\rightarrow M; \delta \rightarrow M$ such that they intersect in a point $\gamma(\lambda_1)=\delta(\lambda_2)= p \in M; \lambda_1,\lambda_2\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $(U,x)$ be an observer chart for the $\gamma$ curve. Let $(V,y)$ be an observer chart for the $\delta$ curve. I just learned that Lorentz transformations can only be done to translate from these two charts in the intersection point. OK. But then I wonder:

Suppose two curves comes from far distance apart from each other. They get very close but never intersect. One event happens when they are getting close and one different event happens when they are getting apart. There is a spacetime interval between these two events right? One observer can estimate the interval as the same as the other observer in the different curve? I know how to calculate the length of the interval(parametrized in a curve $\alpha$):
$$L[\alpha]:=\int_0^1 d\lambda'\sqrt{g\big(v_\alpha(\lambda'),v_\alpha(\lambda') \big)}\;\;;\;\;v_\alpha=(f\circ \alpha)'(\lambda)$$

Comment: “they get very close but never intersect” okay… then you say “one event happens when they are getting close”. What do you mean? Then you write “and one different event happens when they are getting apart”, again this makes no sense (unless you’re more precise). “There is a spacetime interval between these two events right?” well, two events can be separated by a null curve, and there are of course an infinite number of events (even in simple Minkowski space) which are separated by null curves. In this case the integral in question vanishes.

Comment: Your title says Lorentz transformations, but this has nothing whatsoever to do with the ‘length’ of curves, defined by the integral. So, I ask you: what exactly do you wish to know?

Comment: Suppose there is a small curve ($\beta$) near the point where the two curves $\delta,\gamma$ get much closer. Observer $\gamma$ having a Flat metric locally, go and calculate the interval of such curve $\beta$. Observer $\gamma$ do the same. How one observer translate its results/interval if they never intersect? (Supposing they could make a translation via Lorentz Transf only at intersecting points)
@peek-a-boo

Comment: @Acephalus I think, but not sure, that you may be confusing the concept of a tangent space which is indeed a separate space at each point, with the more general notion of a tangent bundle that allows you to define tensor fields on any region of the manifold that's covered by appropriate charts. Then two such compatible charts on such a region can be used to carry out integration, etc. and indeed the results should agree.... please correct me anyone if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @Amit, thanks for the answer. I think I missunderstood something for sure. Let me put in a more clearer picture: Let Bob be in a satelite in orbit to earth, let Ana be in the moon. Now let a commet pass nearby earth. How can both agree in the intervals? They must know the metric of the hole region to calculate it? I dont know by now if I am just repeating myself on non understanding the thing haha

Comment: @Acephalus To calculate anything with the metric you have to represent it as a *chart dependent* $(0,2)$ tensor field. If both Bob and Ana have compatible charts and they calculate or integrate on some spacetime interval that's in the overlap then *yes* their results must agree

Comment: @Amit that enlightened me very much! Thanks